# Update with join using Zend-framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

iam trying to update a table with join using zend on mysql.
Below is the query that I want to do through the zend.
Already thanks.

```
    UPDATE tbproduto  
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT codigo as codTipoProduto, cdTipo FROM tbtipoproduto) as tbtipoproduto ON tbproduto.cdTipoProduto = tbtipoproduto.codTipoProduto 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT codigo as codTipo, descricao as descTipo FROM tbtipo ) as tbTipo ON tbtipoproduto.cdTipo = tbTipo.codTipo
    SET valor = 10.0
    WHERE codigo > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with the 'update()' method provided by the Zend Db Adapter.

You can however, run the query manually using the adapter. Something like:

```
// $adapter is an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter
$adapter->query(YOUR QUERY HERE);
```

Comment: The tricky part here is how to get the number of affected rows. Haven't been able to get that out of it...