# Update join in update sql in zf2

Tags: sql, join, zend-framework2, sql-update

I was trying to figure how to use Update from Zend\Db\Sql using a Join in Zend Framework 2.

In the documentation they say that the only allowed method for Update are just where() and set(), so I would like to know if there are some alternative ways to get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (untested):

```
$db = new DbAdapter(
    array(
        'driver'        => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost',
        'username'       => 'root',
        'password'       => '',
        )
);
$sql = 'UPDATE t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id SET t1.atr = 1';
$sql_result = $db->createStatement($sql )->execute();
if($sql_result->count() > 0){
    echo "DONE";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's actually the way I'm forced doing. 
I'm wondering if there is a "Zf2 way" to do such common operation

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with the 'update()' method provided by the Zend Db Adapter.

You can, however, run the query manually using the adapter. Something like:

// $adapter is an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter
$adapter->query(YOUR QUERY HERE);

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [Update with join using Zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454689/update-with-join-using-zend-framework)

Seems to be no way to do with this with Zend.